# How to extract text from a carousel with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to get the text of [this webpage](http://www.leparisien.fr/elections/municipales/municipales-a-paris-notre-simulateur-pour-savoir-quel-candidat-vous-correspond-le-mieux-05-03-2020-8273238.php) and the following when clicking on the `Oui` or `Non` button, which will be at the same place, and store them as a json file :

[image]

I am open to solutions in javascript and python. I tried teh following one:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('http://www.leparisien.fr/elections/municipales/municipales-a-paris-notre-simulateur-pour-savoir-quel-candidat-vous-correspond-le-mieux-05-03-2020-8273238.php');

    const pollFrame = page.frames().find(
      frame => frame.url() === 'https://livemixr-assets.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/quel-candidat/index.html'
    );

    // getting first question
    const data = await pollFrame.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector('html > body > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > h4').innerText
    );

    console.log(data);

    // clicking on an answer
    await page.$x('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/label[1]')
    const elements = await page.$x('/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/label[1]')
    await elements[0].click()

    // getting second question
    const data2 = await pollFrame.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector('html > body > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > h4').innerText
    );

    console.log(data2);


    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Which get the first text, click on one button, get the second text.
But got the following error:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping>node scraper.js
Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation du métro ?
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at main (C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Scraping\scraper.js:24:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
```

So how to extract text from a webpage with puppeteer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This selector is located inside an iframe, so you need to find this frame first.
2. While you are not so experienced in puppeteer, it would be easier to just use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) (or [`frame.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frameevaluatepagefunction-args)) to get document data by executing web API code in the browser context.

For example:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('http://www.leparisien.fr/elections/municipales/municipales-a-paris-notre-simulateur-pour-savoir-quel-candidat-vous-correspond-le-mieux-05-03-2020-8273238.php');

    await page.waitForSelector('iframe[src="https://livemixr-assets.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/quel-candidat/index.html"]');

    const pollFrame = page.frames().find(
      frame => frame.url() === 'https://livemixr-assets.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/quel-candidat/index.html'
    );

    const data = await pollFrame.evaluate(() => {
      const texts = [];
      while (document.querySelector('div.ant-modal-content') === null) {
        texts.push(document.querySelector('div:nth-child(5) > h4').innerText);

        document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')[1].click();
        // or: document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][value="Non"]').click();
      }
      return texts;
    });

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Output:

```
[
  'Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation du métro ?',
  'Faut-il faire payer le stationnement des deux-roues ?',
  'Faut-il interdire les bus de tourisme dans la capitale ?',
  'Faut-il piétonniser les quatre arrondissements centraux de la capitale ?',
  'Faut-il réduire le nombre de places de stationnement en surface ?',
  "Faut-il rendre le Vélib' gratuit ?",
  'Faut-il renforcer la vidéoverbalisation ?',
  'Faut-il rouvrir à la circulation les voies sur berges ?',
  'Faut-il interdire les trottinettes électriques ? (free floating)',
  'Le périphérique doit-il...',
  'Les transports doivent-ils être rendus gratuits...',
  "Faut-il demander l'annulation des Jeux olympiques ?",
  'Faut-il mettre fin à la pratique du tirage au sort pour le conservatoire ?',
  'Faut-il augmenter le nombre de caméras de vidéo-surveillance dans la rue ?',
  'Faut-il créér une police municipale ?',
  'Le future police municipale doit-elle être armée ?',
  "Faut-il augmenter le montant des amendes (jets de mégots, urine, dépôt d'ordures...) ?",
  'Faut-il privatiser le ramassage des déchets ?',
  'À Paris, la société Airbnb doit-elle être ...',
  'Faut-il baisser le nombre de nuitées autorisées à la location sur Airbnb (120 jours actuellement) ?',
  "Faut-il maintenir l'encadrement des loyers?",
  "En priorité, l'accès au logement social doit-il être attribué ...",
  'Faut-il accroître le nombre de logements sociaux ?',
  'En matière de finances, faut-il ...',
  'Faut-il interdire les animaux sauvages dans les cirques ?',
  'Faut-il proposer une alternative végétarienne tous les jours dans les cantines ?',
  'Faut-il piétonniser les abords des écoles ?',
  "Quelle est la priorité pour améliorer l'environnement ?",
  'En cas de grèves, faut-il un service minimum pour les crèches et les écoles ?',
  'Faut-il revenir à la semaine de 4 jours dans les écoles ?',
  'Les tarifs des cantines scolaires doivent-ils ... ?',
  'Faut-il étendre le travail du dimanche ?'
]
```

Comment: Mancy thanks ! I'm sorry to bother you again, but how do I get get the text of the following items when clicking on the `Oui` or `Non` button?

Comment: We need to get the text, click on the button (by order or value) end check if this is the end by checking some final element — all this in a loop. I've updated the example.

Comment: BTW, in your updated variant you need to use `pollFrame`, not `page` in all next lines after we find the iframe, as all other needed elements are still located in this iframe.

Comment: And beware that input values not always are `Oui` or `Non`, there are some other variants.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how to get  the whole thing of what's with `...`?

Comment: The rest text is in the same `'input[type="radio"]'` elements. You can check if the main text ends with `...` or if the radio inputs are not `Oui` or `Non` and add theirs `.value` properties to the text instead of `...`.